# HTML DIV is not moving from right to left diagonally towards end

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-selectors

```css
      <style>
        #container {
          width: 400px;
          height: 400px;
          position: relative;
          background: rgb(240, 240, 231);
        }
    
        #animate {
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          position: absolute;
          background-color: red;
        }
    
        #animate1 {
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          left: 350px;
          top: 2px;
          position: absolute;
          background-color: rgb(43, 1, 1);
        }
      </style>
```

```html
        <p>
          <button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button>
        </p>
    
        <div id="container">
          <div id="animate"></div>
          <div id="animate1"></div>
        </div>
    
        <script>
          function myMove() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
            var elem1 = document.getElementById("animate1");
    
            var pos = 0;
            var pos1 = 0;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
            var id1 = setInterval(frame1, 5);
    
            function frame() {
              if (pos == 350) {
                clearInterval(id);
              } else {
                pos++;
                elem.style.top = pos + "px";
                elem.style.left = pos + "px";
              }
            }
    
            function frame1() {
              if (pos1 == 350) {
                clearInterval(id1);
              } else {
                pos1++;
                elem1.style.top = pos1 + "px";
                elem1.style.right = pos1 + "px";
              }
            }
          }
        </script>
```

> In the above code I have 2 cubes(div). On click of button, the left cube should move from left to right till the end of the container diagonally and right cube should move from right to left diagonally till the end of the container. But only left cube is moving from left to right and right cube is moving from top to bottom. **I want right cube to be moved from right to left diagonally till the end of the container**. And this is my sandbox link. https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-sun-uz961?file=/index.html

Answer (score 0):

.animate1 class has left:350px make it to right:0 it will work.

```js
function myMove() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
        var elem1 = document.getElementById("animate1");

        var pos = 0;
        var pos1 = 0;
        var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
        var id1 = setInterval(frame1, 5);

        function frame() {
          if (pos == 350) {
            clearInterval(id);
          } else {
            pos++;
            elem.style.top = pos + "px";
            elem.style.left = pos + "px";
          }
        }

        function frame1() {
          if (pos1 == 350) {
            clearInterval(id1);
          } else {
            pos1++;
            elem1.style.top = pos1 + "px";
            elem1.style.right = pos1 + "px";
          }
        }
      }
```

```css
    #container {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      position: relative;
      background: rgb(240, 240, 231);
    }

    #animate {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: red;
    }

    #animate1 {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      right:0px;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: rgb(43, 1, 1);
    }
```

```html
<p>
      <button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button>
    </p>

    <div id="container">
      <div id="animate"></div>
      <div id="animate1"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your css and change `left: 350px;` to `right: 0px;` for `#animate1` :

```js
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
  var elem1 = document.getElementById("animate1");

  var pos = 0;
  var pos1 = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  var id1 = setInterval(frame1, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + "px";
      elem.style.left = pos + "px";
    }
  }

  function frame1() {
    if (pos1 == 350) {
      clearInterval(id1);
    } else {
      pos1++;
      elem1.style.top = pos1 + "px";
      elem1.style.right = pos1 + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(240, 240, 231);
}

#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}

#animate1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  right: 0px; /* instead of right : 350px; */
  top: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(43, 1, 1);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button>
</p>

<div id="container">
  <div id="animate"></div>
  <div id="animate1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Off Topic, but are you aware of CSS transitions?

```js
function myMove() {
  document.getElementById("animate").classList.toggle("move");
  document.getElementById("animate1").classList.toggle("move");
}

// try clicking the boxes themselves
for (let item of document.querySelectorAll("#animate, #animate1")) {
  item.onclick = function() {
    item.classList.toggle("move");
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(240, 240, 231);
}

#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  transition: 3s linear;
}

#animate.move {
  top: 350px;
  left: 350px;
}

#animate1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(43, 1, 1);
  transition: 3s linear;
}

#animate1.move {
  top: 350px;
  right: 350px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button>
</p>

<div id="container">
  <div id="animate"></div>
  <div id="animate1"></div>
</div>
```